# Getting "Invariant Violation" error when adding {/* comment */} into return function in react native

Tags: react-native, jsx

I am currently learning react native and just figured out that when applying the following code:

```
return (
    <View>
        <TextInput
            placeholder="Enter a goal"
        />
        <Button title="ADD" /> {/*This button is cool*/}
    </View>
)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.

However, the error disappears if I am not using a self-closing `<Button />` tag, but instead place my comment inside of it:

`<Button>{/* Comment */}</Button>`.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this Button component is react native Button component ?

Comment: you have to add every text in some Component otherwise it will give the respective error... Just give your text to some Text Component or make your own button which take text as a props

Comment: I just thought that a comment is not a text, as it is not rendered into the app... So I am just confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is when you do this

```
<Button title="ADD" /> {/*This button is cool*/}
```

i.e add comments after the the jsx tag , it means its considering comment as a Text string , not as a comment because its in the same line as that of a tag, since this is a property of JSX, but in javascript you could have done like

`var a = 10 // this is variable`, <-- and this will be considered a comments.

but when you do as you said  ,

`<Button>{/* Comment */}</Button>.` it considers it as a comments as its enclosed between 2 tags. And another fun thing , 
if you place your comment just above your button tag, it doesnt throw error, just becuase its in a different line.

```
 {/*This button is cool*/}
 <Button title="ADD" />
```